# Moment is getting the wrong date in Node JS mssql query

Tags: node.js, sql-server, momentjs

I am trying to pass moment dates as variables in a query. When I console log the dates are correct but when the query runs it gets the current date -1...

Here is the code:

```
const dateEnd = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59');
const dateStart = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00');

      // console.log(dateEnd)<-- They come back correct
      // console.log(dateStart)
      // process.exit();

      let pool = await sql.connect(dbconfig)
       //Get records from table
        let getRecords = await pool.request()
            .input('dateStart', sql.Date, dateStart)
            .input('incrm', sql.VarChar, 'yes')
            .input('dateEnd', sql.Date, dateEnd)
            .query('select * from database.dbo.table where someValue in (231312,7132133) and incrm=@incrm and processeddate between @dateStart and @dateEnd and email is not null')
```

Comment: Could it be a timezone issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `node-mssql` library expects dates to be passed as `Date` objects.

Try this, if you want the current day in the same time zone as the machine you're running this code from:

```
const dateStart = moment().startOf('day').toDate();
const dateEnd = moment().endOf('day').toDate();
```

Or, if you want the current UTC day, then:

```
const dateStart = moment.utc().startOf('day').toDate();
const dateEnd = moment.utc().endOf('day').toDate();
```

Or, if you want the current day in a particular time zone (say US Central Time), then use the moment-timezone add-on library:

```
const dateStart = moment.tz('America/Chicago').startOf('day').toDate();
const dateEnd = moment.tz('America/Chicago').endOf('day').toDate();
```

All three of these assume that the `processeddate` is in terms of UTC in your database.

You should probably also pass `sql.DateTime2` instead of `sql.Date`.